# Finding the median value from a PDF

Tags: statistics, density-function, cumulative-distribution-functions, median, quantile

Suppose that the time in days until hospital discharge for a certain patient population follows a density $f(x) = (0.5)\exp(-x/2)$ for $x > 0$.  What is the median discharge time in days?

I reason that the median is equivalent to the value of x that gives us the 50% quantile.  In other words $F(x) = 0.5$.  So I must determine the CDF from the PDF, which I believe is $-\exp(-x/2)$, and then solve for $x$ in $-\exp(-x/2) = 0.5$.

However this poses a problem.  Instinctively, I want to take the natural log of both sides, but I don't believe I can do this without having to start incorporating imaginary numbers into my solution.  I know for a fact that the actual solution must be a real-valued number, and since we're talking about a solution measured in terms of number-of-days, the solution cannot be negative either.

So, either I am missing something that would allow me to rearrange this equation and meet these criteria, or it could be that my CDF is simply incorrect.

Comment: CDFs cannot take on negative values as you claim in $-\exp(-x/2)$.  You are confusing between the _antiderivative_ of $\frac  12\exp(-x/2), x>0$ and its _integral_ from $-\infty$ to $x$ which is the same as the _integral_ from $0$ to $x$..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CDF if
$$
F(x) = \int_0^xf(t)\,\mathrm{d}t = -e^{-t/2}{\large|}_0^x = 1 - e^{-x/2}. 
$$
Therefore, setting $F(x)=1/2$ we het
$$
1-e^{-x/2} = \frac{1}{2}
$$
So $e^{-x/2} = \frac{1}{2} \iff e^{x/2} = 2$. This yields $x = 2\log(2)$.

Comment: That's a good point!  I forgot to consider that possibility.  Just tried it out, and it works!